# Angular 4 & Web Api web service when deployed in production under SSL

Tags: angular, ssl, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2008-r2

We developed front-end site using angular 4 & back end service using asp.net MVC web API & we it is working in development server & tested , but when we deployed them in production server (windows server 2008 R2 IIS 8) under SSL certificate the operations create & update not working anymore just when I tried to implement these operation from outside the server otherwise if I tried them from the server machine they working normally. for example when i add customer from angular site to WebAPI item parameter received with null value in WebAPI, i tried it also using postman

```
[Route("Add")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Add(PeriodCategoryCriteria item)
    {
        // Add Data in Data Base
    }
```

do you have any ideas how we can solve this issue ?